# Animation - Drawing a circle in iOS - Not animating complete circle

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using the following code to draw part of a circle. I'm a bit confused, however, because at the end of the animation it seems to immediately fill in the rest of the circle. Why is this happening?

```
// Set up the shape of the circle
int radius = 62;
CAShapeLayer *circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
// Make a circular shape
circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2.0*radius, 2.0*radius)
                                         cornerRadius:radius].CGPath;
// Center the shape in self.view
circle.position = CGPointMake(18, 92);

// Configure the apperence of the circle
circle.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
circle.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
circle.lineWidth = 5;

// Add to parent layer
[cell.layer addSublayer:circle];

// Configure animation
CABasicAnimation *drawAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
drawAnimation.duration            = .8; // "animate over 10 seconds or so.."
drawAnimation.repeatCount         = 1.0;  // Animate only once..

// Animate from no part of the stroke being drawn to the entire stroke being drawn
drawAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
drawAnimation.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f];

// Experiment with timing to get the appearence to look the way you want
drawAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because by default a `CAAnimation` is removed from the layer when it completes. This means that it will remove the value that you animated to and set it to the default of `1.0` right after the animation finished. Since you are using a `CAAnimation` the layer is never actually changing its properties it just only looks like it is which is why when the animation is removed it gets set to `1.0` because that is what the layer's value for `strokeEnd` is since you never changed it. Try to see this yourself by printing the value of `strokeEnd` while the animation is happening.

This can be solved in 2 ways, setting the final `storkeEnd` value before you start the animation so that when it is removed it is still `0.4` or by adding certain properties to your `CABasicAnimation`. The properties you need to set to achieve what you are looking for are:

`drawAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards`

and

`drawAnimation.removedOnCompletion = false`

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

For the whole stroke to be animated `drawAnimation.fromValue` should be `0.0` and `drawAnimation.toValue` should be `1.0`. These values determine what percentage of the stroke is animated.

```
drawAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
drawAnimation.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];

fromValue : Defines the value the receiver uses to start interpolation.
toValue : Defines the value the receiver uses to end interpolation.
```

What you used was `0.4` for `drawAnimation.toValue`. So it ends at `40%` of the animation and draws the rest in one go without animating.

For example if you set `drawAnimation.fromValue = 0.5` and  `drawAnimation.toValue = 1.0`,
animation will start from half a circle.
if you set `drawAnimation.fromValue = 0.0` and  `drawAnimation.toValue = 0.5`,
animation will end at half a circle and draw the rest without animation.

If you only wanted to draw 40% of the circle, you can use a different function to create the circle path.

```
CGFloat startAngle = (-M_PI/2);
CGFloat endAngle = startAngle + 0.4*(2*M_PI);

circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(radius, radius)
                                                      radius:radius
                                                  startAngle:startAngle
                                                    endAngle:endAngle
                                                   clockwise:YES].CGPath;
```

The above code actually generates  40% of a circle path from `startAngle = -M_PI/2`. You can vary the angle according to your needs.

Comment: I see. And how do I get around this so I only draw 40% of the circle?

Comment: oh you want to draw only 40% of the circle? and not the rest?